# Jquery "address" is not working on refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery address and I can't get it to initialize on refresh...(In all major browsers except IE) Here are the issues...

When I click on a link the ajax loads it loads perfectly and adds the class "selected" to the link as it is supposed to. When I use the back button it works perfect also, but after I click the link then hit the refresh button, it reloads the original state (minus the ajax) and will not add the class "selected" to any links or load anymore ajax thereafter.

Here is the link to the page. http://www.weightlossexp.com/articles

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

**[Edit] Code**

Jquery

```
var init = true, 
        state = window.history.pushState !== undefined;
        // Handles response
        var handler = function(data,topic,w) {
          $("#title_back h1").hide().html(topic).fadeIn(800);
          $('title').html(topic);
          $('#content').html(data).animate({width:w},1500);
          $('#lc').show();
          // $.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
        };
        $.address.state('/articles').init(function() {
            // Initializes the plugin
            $('#lc a').address();                
        }).change(function(event) {
            // Selects the proper navigation link
            $('#lc a').each(function() {
                //alert($(this).attr('href')+' - - '+$.address.state() + event.path);
                if ($(this).attr('href') == ($.address.state() + event.path)) {
                    $(this).addClass('selected').focus();
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                }
            });
            var classL = $(".selected").length;
            if(classL == 1){
                var topic = $('.selected h2').html();
                var action = event.path.substr(1);
                var width = '100%';
            }else{ 
                var topic = "Topics"; 
                var action = '';
                var width = '0px';
            }
            if (state && init) {
                init = false;
            } else {
                // Loads the page content and inserts it into the content area
                $.ajax({
                    url: "scripts/ajax/getSubTitles.php",
                    data: {action:action},
                    type: "post",
                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        handler(data,topic,width);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Html

```
<div id="lc" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden;">
                    <a href="/articles/ap" id="ap"><div class="topics" style="border-top:1px solid #d1d1d1; margin-top:20px;"><h2>Anatomy and Physiology</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/end" id="end"><div class="topics"><h2>Endurance</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/flex" id="flex"><div class="topics"><h2>Flexibility</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/myth" id="myth"><div class="topics"><h2>Myths</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/nut" id="nut"><div class="topics"><h2>Nutrition 101</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/corr" id="corr"><div class="topics"><h2>Post-Rehab/Corrective Exercise</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/power" id="power"><div class="topics"><h2>Power</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/stab" id="stab"><div class="topics"><h2>Stability</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/str" id="str"><div class="topics"><h2>Strength/Resistance Training</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/supp" id="supp"><div class="topics"><h2>Supplements</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/wg" id="wg"><div class="topics"><h2>Weight Gain</h2></div></a>
                    <a href="/articles/wl" id="wl"><div class="topics"><h2>Weight Loss</h2></div></a>
                <div id="content">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code is that in the lines which you have included your javascripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.address-1.5.min.js"></script>
```

after clicking on the link, the URL will change from

> http://www.weightlossexp.com/articles

to

> http://www.weightlossexp.com/articles/something

and those two **js** files can not be found in the new url so both jquery and jquery.address will not be loaded.

just start the path of your JS files with a slash '/' and your code will work fine.

so the code will be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.address-1.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well that definitely helped, but it did not fix the problem entirely. All the links work now, but it still will not reload the content on refresh.

Comment: I see, the problem is that, after loading the page, you should check to see if you are in the root of articles or in one of those links, then you have to show the 'content' div and hind 'lc' div.

Comment: Hey, Im having the same problem on a different site, but your fix doesn't seem to be working... Can you check it out for me and tell me why it won't refresh or load in a new tab? hw.weightlossexp.com

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the problem you are facing the the new site?

Comment: if you go to http://hw.weightlossexp.com/index/gallary it gives me a 404 error. If you go to the domain and use the nav links they work perfectly... Here is another SO question I opened to get this resolved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578306/jquery-address-is-not-working-on-refresh